# PopUp Message while navigating from one aspx page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can anybody help me out with the popup message related concept in `ASP.NET`.
I have been working in `ASP.NET MVC`, and I am getting no popup message with the below code while navigating from one aspx page to another.

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Data is Updated')</script>");    
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
```

Comment: Your redirect is masking the pop up.  Comment out the second line to test.  Then consider using JavaScript / JQuery to wait for the user's response before redirect.

Comment: yes when i do comment the second line it works fine but the thing is that, I am executing sqlcommand and after getting successfull execution i have to display the message accordingly. Is not there any other way to do so except javascript?

Comment: Not with the way you're attempting.  Why not pass the success message as an url parameter in your redirect and display it on WebForm2.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up is not occurring because of the redirect.  Both the alert and the redirect are being done in server-side code.  There is no way to wait for user interaction on the client side because the server-side code has already executed by the time the user sees it.

You could move the alert and redirect to client side JavaScript.  The redirect would not fire until the alert is closed.

```
alert("Successful");
window.location = "WebForm2.aspx";
```

Or, you could send the message as an url parameter in your server-side redirect, and handle the message display on WebForm2.aspx.

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?status=successful");
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion ,But #Mr.devlin this method is not working, it directly goes to the WebForm2. I want the pop up to be displayed on the server side. When i use javascript, i can compare only user data related things. I want want that if there is a problem with the server, like if i am updating any entry in the server using ADO.net it should give me a popup message that entry is updated or not..

Comment: If you know please tell me

Comment: @Nik - It's not possible the way you're attempting to do it.  Sorry.  You need to find another way.  I've suggested two options.

Comment: Okay devlin carnate, thanks for your valuable suggestion